# Available phenotype data from GTEx

Tags: gene, public-databases, gene-expression, public-dataset, gtex

I am using gene expression data from the The Genotype-Tissue Expression (GTEx) project, available here: http://gtexportal.org. I would also like to use phenotype data for each sample (especially age, sex, race, body mass index, smoking history).

Access to such information is controlled by the NIH, so you need to apply for access.

Before I go through that probably lengthy process, I would like to know if it is worth it. **Are any of the phenotype data age, sex, race, body mass index, smoking history available on a per-sample level, if you have access?** I could not find this information anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If helpful for anyone else, I found that all and much more are available. See below 2 links.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/gap/cgi-bin/dataset.cgi?study_id=phs000424.v8.p2&phv=169091&phd=3910&pha=&pht=2742&phvf=&phdf=&phaf=&phtf=&dssp=1&consent=&temp=1

https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/dbgap/studies/phs000424/phs000424.v8.p2/pheno_variable_summaries/phs000424.v8.pht002742.v8.p2.GTEx_Subject_Phenotypes.var_report.xml